# Zero response through http-proxy-middleware

Tags: javascript, express, http-proxy, http-proxy-middleware

I am trying to debug a proxy in Express, using `http-proxy-middleware`, but no matter what I do I get absolutely zero response. The endpoint sends the response but it is never returned by the proxy and the `onProxyRes` event is never triggered. Also the endpoint can be accessed directly through `curl`, Insomnia, `fetch` API and `request-promise` and is in use as an API for our customers.

Even with a setup as simple as:

```
app.use('/api', proxy({
  target: 'https://my.secret.endpoint',
  changeOrigin: true
});
```

I get absolutely zero response, except for a `ECONNRESET` after timeout. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

Heureka! I found the answer I was looking for! The offending party was (in my case) the `express.urlencoded()` middleware, which does some trickery that ultimately messes up the proxy. This can be resolved by applying the offending middleware after the proxy. Other middleware that might do this include `cookie-parser`and `bodyParser` (both of which are deprecated).

More on the issue here: https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/issues/40

Comment: Same to me. This also explains why it only happened to me on POST request with a request body, but not on a regular GET request. Thank you so much.

Comment: This saved me many more hours, I spent on it the entire day

Answer (score 2):

ViggoV
You need to disable the SSL when the target is https.

Like as this:

```
app.use('/api', proxy({
  target: 'https://my.secret.endpoint',
  changeOrigin: true,
  secure: false
});
```

Comment: As you can see from my own answer I managed to fix it by other means. However it somehow works without `secure: false`, but it may be because both projects (api backend and express server) run within the same secure network(?). I'll definitely keep it in mind if I run into trouble when we take it into production. Thanks for the input in any case :)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution for anyone coming here with the same issue but did not solve it.

In proxy configuration make sure you are matching any path
with double ** not only *

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy("/api/**", { // https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware
    target: "http://localhost:5000",
    secure: false
  }));
};
```

For more check this [reference](http://%20https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware)

Comment: Yes. This was my issue - after setting context to `/**`, as opposed to `/*`, the proxy finally started forwarding requests.